Ambiguity with plus or minus sign to indicate points
In my textbook there are sometimes points in the form $P(\pm a ; \pm b) \hspace{4cm}$(1).
This nevertheless is really ambiguous; as I understand, it could be either $P_1 (a;b)$ and $P_2(-a;-b)$ or all the possible combinations: maybe a clearer way to express those 4 points is $P_{1;2}(\pm a;b)$ and $P_{3;4} (\pm a ; -b)$
Is there a correct way to interpret the (1) or is it just ambiguous?
Edit: an example is $$\begin {cases}
x^2+y^2=1\\ 
|y|=2|x|
\end{cases}
 \Longrightarrow x^2=\dfrac{1}{5} \Longrightarrow x =\pm \dfrac{\sqrt5}{5}$$
We also have $y=\pm 2x$ so the points are $ \left(\pm \dfrac{\sqrt5}{5}; \dfrac{2\sqrt5}{5} \right)$ and $ \left(\pm \dfrac{\sqrt5}{5}; - \dfrac{2\sqrt5}{5} \right)$ My book has as solution $ \left(\pm \dfrac{\sqrt5}{5}; 
\pm \dfrac{2\sqrt5}{5} \right)$

There really isn't any agreed upon convention for this. If $\pm$ comes with $\mp$ the $\mp$'is the opposite sign. But two $\pm$ is context-dependent. There isn't a formal meaning to $\pm,$ as usually used.

I think it would be helpful if you gave a more specific quote from your textbook. I think it is usual to interpret multiple instances of $\pm$ as being independent: so  if you have $2$ instances of $\pm$, that's an abbreviation for $4$ cases.

Well I see this notation in the solutions of many problems, as example a system of equations

So give us a specific example, then we may be able to give you some help without guesswork on our part. Help us to help you!

Edited, my question is general by the way: I am trying to know if there is a convention or if this is just bad notation

$y=\pm x$ is shorthand for the disjunction "$y=-x$ OR $y=x$"; so, in the absence of context, $y=\pm x\pm z$ and $\pm y\ne \pm x,$ and even $y\ne\pm x,$ are all ambiguous.

Oh okay so logically when I say $x \neq \pm y$ it is only needed that at least one condition, either $x \neq y$ or $x \neq -y$ is satisfied. This, however, isn't correct since I need for both condition to be true at the same time. So this notation isn't just ambiguous, it is just wrong, am I right?
